# Angular How to inject service into .run(function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I would like to ask, how to inject service into app.js file in Angular app ?(In my case service called DialService).

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function(DialService) {
```

If I'm trying to call service method, for example:

```
DialService.makeCall(jsonObj.phone_number);
```

I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'makeCall' of undefined

How can i call service method in app.js ?

Thanks for any help.

**Service is following:**

```
/**
 * Service for making calls
 */
.factory('DialService', function($ionicLoading) {
    return {
        makeCall: function(number) {
            window.cordova.plugins.DirectCallPlugin.call(number, callSuccessCallback, callFailCallback);
        }
    };

    var callSuccessCallback = function() {
        console.log("Success call");
    };

    var callFailCallback = function() {
        console.log("Fail calll");
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Error during call dial',
            duration: 1000
        });
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a service during `run` phase. What you want is using a `provider`.

Transform this :

```
.factory('DialService', function($ionicLoading) {
```

into this :

```
.provider('DialService', function($ionicLoading) {
```

And, as providers are "service like", you don't need to return anything, but need yo add your methods to the provider object :

```
this.makeCall = function(number) {
  window.cordova.plugins.DirectCallPlugin.call(number, callSuccessCallback, callFailCallback);
}

function callSuccessCallback () {
  console.log("Success call");
};

function callFailCallback () {
  console.log("Fail calll");
  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: 'Error during call dial',
    duration: 1000
  });
};
```